# submit only specific fields in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this

```
 <div id="list">
 <form>
      <div id="first">
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="third"> third</label>
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="fourth"> fourth</label>
      </div>

      <div id="second">
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="first"> first</label>
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="second"> second</label>
      </div>

     <div id="fake-list-sorted-alphabetically">
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="first"> first</label>
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="second"> second</label>
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="third"> first</label>
           <label><input type="checkbox" value="fourth"> second</label>
     </div>
 </form>
 </div>
```

would it just be possible with the $.ajax to serialize only the checkbox values from div#first, div#second and ignore everything from #fake? right now I'm just doing a $('#fake').html(""); right before I submit but that feels hacky. The reason I don't have #fake outside of the form is because I need it to display in the same container as #first and #second as part of a view all function

Comment: Seems like it would be easier/cleaner to just have separate forms.

Comment: Just place `#fake` _outside_ of the `form` element ...

Comment: why have you omitted name attributes on your inputs?

Comment: Are saying you're already using `$.ajax()`? If so, please show your JS code so we can see how you gather the values and suggest changes. If you are doing a standard form submit then none of those checkboxes would be submitted because they don't have `name` attributes.

Comment: Why not just send all the data and ignore what you don't want at the server end?

Comment: I've revised the question

Comment: Consider disabling the controls you don't want submitted. BTW, the controls in *fake-list* don't have names and so can't be successful, therefore they shouldn't be submitted anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('#first input').serialize();
```

Based on your updated question:

```
$('form div:not(#fake-list-sorted-alphabetically) :input').serialize()
```

Comment: revised original question, what If there's more than one div I wanna serialize?

Comment: So are you really asking for all form fields except those in `#fake-list-sorted-alphabetically`?  You could have 100 divs you want values from and a single one that you don't?

Answer (score 2):

There're array of input fields: `var data = $("#first input").serializeArray();`

To submit form with ajax: `$.post("you action url", data);`

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 1):

You can gather just the data you want into an object and pass that object to your ajax call to send it to the server. If you're using a submit button, you can bind a click handler to it and use event.preventDefault() on the event to stop it from submitting everything. After that, go ahead and use jquery to grab the values you want from the form and then make the ajax call with that data.